# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular2-router-loader'

Tags: angular, webpack, .net-core

I just created angular project on vs .net core 2.0.

After installing

```
npm install --save angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker bootstrap moment open-iconic
```

There was no error arise on installation.

Not a single line of new manual code added to project, and when I run the project

I am facing this error : (which i don't understand*)

ERROR in multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular2-router-loader' in 'F:\migroNgVsCore2\MigrologyV2\WebApplication'
 @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts

**What I tried :**  But that is not helpfull too.

```
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true,
                HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
npm install -g angular2-router-loader